# Change command line for external editor in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, weka

I use Weka to generate ARFF files, and I would like to open them from my Eclipse (Kepler) environment. When I double click on the ARFF file, Eclipse starts Weka but the parameters are not correct since Weka raises an "OutOfMemory" error after a few seconds. So I would like to change the command used by Eclipse to start Weka, but I can not find it !

I have searched extensively in the Preferences / Editors menu in Eclipse, but I can not see the command line used by Eclipse, so I can not specify the -Xmx argument to increase the amount of memory !

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks in advance,

Gilles

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good feature request for Eclipse.

The closest solution to your task is to use the External Tools function in Eclipse.

In Eclipse, go to Run-External Tools.  Create a new Program launch configuration and add the arguments in the provided field.

https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-exttools-running.htm